# Any open source projects using Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: open-source, workflow-foundation

I am attempting to understand and use Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) and I find it useful to study "real" as well as "sample" applications.

Does anyone know of some open source projects that incorporate WF that I could study?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for study try [hands on lab](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2e575633-e357-4ee7-aaff-34138f00e830&DisplayLang=en)
and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/UnderstandWWF.aspx) might help you understand it
and here is some example from real life http://sourceforge.net/projects/sinergia/

Comment: Thanks for the link to sinerga. I wish it was upgraded to 4.0 though.